# How do i import a sqlite db file in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application I can export the database db to /Android/data.... , now i want to reverse it, i want to Import it.

```
    public boolean importDatabase() throws IOException {
            close();
            // Close the SQLiteOpenHelper so it will commit the created empty
            // database to internal storage.
         File newDb = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Android/data/com.dreamhawk.ea/files/");
        // File newDb = new File(dbPath);

            File oldDb = new File(NotesDbAdapter.DB_FILEPATH);
            if (newDb.exists()) {
                Prefs.copyFile(newDb, oldDb);
                // Access the copied database so SQLiteHelper will cache it and mark
                // it as created.
                getWritableDatabase().close();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

This is what I've came up with so far. However, i get an

```
The method `close()` is undefined for the type Prefs
```

On `close()`.

And I get

```
The method `getWritableDatabase()` is undefined for the type Prefs
```

On `getWritableDatabase().close();`

I am using this function in my Preference-class called "Prefs". 
And i am thinking that i need to fetch some functions from my dbadapter, called NotesDbAdapter.

However, it wont work with , for example `NotesDbAdapter.getWritableDatabase.close();` either.

Edit: I Put it in the NotesDbAdapter in SQLiteOpenHelper { }.
This removed all the errors...

Now to the next problem, i want to call this function, when a user presses a Custom Preference.

```
     Preference restoreToDb = (Preference) findPreference("restoreFromSd");
 restoreToDb.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

     File dbPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Android/data/com.dreamhawk.ea/files/");
    // String dbPath = "/Android/data/com.dreamhawk.ea/files/";
     public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            //NotesDbAdapter.importDatabase(); <-- help here?
            return true;

 }
 });
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a solution here.